# COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirements.txt: file does not exist ERROR

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am able to build my docker image and run it locally. But when I am trying to deploy same docker image on cloud run its getting failed during code build and giving below error.

```
Step 9/11 : COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat requirements.txt: file does not exist
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Here is Dockerfile at the root level of the project.

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV PORT 5000
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 driver:app
```

I am depolying from local using command below.

```
gcloud run deploy cloud-run-flask-testing --region=asia-south1 --source=$(pwd) --allow-unauthenticated
```

Adding dockerignore file for reference.

```
Dockerfile
README.md
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.pyd
__pycache__
.pytest_cache
```

Attaching project directory structure for reference. Any help highly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: *But when I am trying to deploy same docker image on cloud* it sounds like this isn't correct. You're trying to build it, not deploy it. It looks like the remote repository being used does not have `requirements.txt`.

Comment: I am not using remote repositiory ci/cd to deploy but from local only using command below
gcloud run deploy cloud-run-flask-testing --region=asia-south1 --source=$(pwd) --allow-unauthenticated

Answer (score 0):

I had .txt in my .gitignore which was ignoring requirements.txt file being used in codebuild source code.

```
*env*
*csv*
*txt*
*json*
*__pycache__*
*idea*
.git
```

Removing *txt* worked. Flask api deployed to cloud run successfully.